# How to test Cassandra performance?

Tags: performance, testing, cassandra

I would like to test several Cassandra drivers( such as thrift and avro)?

What test should be best to define **most performance** connection scheme?

(Most performance probably means - the fastest writing/reading).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, when it comes to drivers, I wouldn't worry about things like "Thrift" or "Avro" since the underlying RPC mechanism is an implementation detail.  That said, it's worth noting that Avro RPC was a short-lived experiment and is no longer present in any modern version of Cassandra.

Your choice of interface for versions of Cassandra >= 0.8.0 boils down to either a third-party wrapper to the RPC interface (Thrift), or CQL.

CQL is an SQL-alike query language that makes writing applications much simpler.  If you're just starting out, I would definitely recommend looking into it.

For RPC wrappers, a current(ish) list of options can be found on the ClientOptions page of the Cassandra wiki, and CQL drivers are hosted on Google Code/Apache Extras, (tagged Cassandra).

As to which of these two interfaces is fastest, the short answer is: Thrift RPC is faster.  *However*, the difference is quite small (~10%), and limited to non-indexed insertions (all other operations are comparable in performance). Also, with the release of Cassandra 1.1 (due out in March), CQL will support prepared statements which make CQL faster *across the board*, up to 16% faster.

For some CQL/Thrift performance results relevant to current versions of cassandra see [this post](http://www.acunu.com/blogs/eric-evans/cql-benchmarking).  For results applicable to the forthcoming 1.1 release see the results attached to this [Cassandra JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3634) (scroll down).

*That being said*, you should always conduct your own tests in an environment that is as close to your production setup as possible, using a mixture of operations that most closely resembles what you expect to see from your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, the problem we have - We got several Ruby applications <-> ruby gem 'thrift' <-through thrift rpc-> cassandra and we are being upset of 'thrift' gem since it is not always provide as much performance as we need, so we are just looking on possible alternatives to use cassandra from ruby or (possible solution) from java(since we can use jruby if it will be neccessary).

Comment: So, - currently all cql implementations for ruby are using thrift gem, which is makes cql features that will be introduced in Cassandra 1.1 unneccessary for us.

Comment: Also, I found that all CQL driver currently use Thrift anyway as RPC stack, so, I am curios - why CQL  beat Thrift after 1.1?

Comment: CQL uses Thrift for transport (for now), but query processing happens entirely server-side (Thrift is just used to get it there).  It is faster in Cassandra 1.1 (with prepared statements) because it is more compact on the wire, requires less processing, and generates less work for the garbage collector.

Comment: Ruby's thrift processing is exceptionally slow, even with the C extension.  Assuming CQL-over-thrift hits the same bottleneck (and I see no reason it would not), your options include 1. working on the non-Thrift CQL transport (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2478), 2. try to optimize the C extension, 3. switch to a different language, or 4. throw hardware at the problem.

So far most people seem to be going with a mix of 3. and 4. :)

Comment: I should add that JRuby might be an easier variant of "switch to a different language."  Java Thrift performance is fantastic.

Comment: Curious, what is more rational - optimize C extension of ruby gem 'thrift' or move into jruby and make 'thrift' gem use just ruby code, without C extension.